# How to prove these two sets are equal to each other?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have recently come across this problem and am having trouble proving they are equal sets. I can prove that the second set is a subset of the first through plugging in (8x-14) into x, but can't find a good way to prove the first set is a subset of the second to prove their equality.

$$\{x\in \mathbb{Z} : 7|x\} = \{x\in \mathbb{Z} : 7|(8x-14)\}$$

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Using properties of divisibility, $7|x\iff 7|(x+7(x-2))$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Thanks! I don't really see how those are the same. Can you explain this further? Maybe I'm not seeing it even though its obvious to you. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint.
$$8x-14=x+7x-14=x+7(x-2)$$

Comment: Yeah i somewhat understand the idea of splitting it into multiples of 7 and I got here too but don't really understand how to simplify this

Comment: @tomas31827. The way is following: because we have equality $A=B+7C$, then $7|A \Leftrightarrow 7|B$. I.e let's assume $7|A$, then $B= A-7C$ and so $7|B$. Now if $7|B$, then  $7|(B+7C)$ and so $7|A$.

Answer (score 0):

This seems more an exercise in divisibility than one in set theory.

$7|x$ means there is some integer $k$ such that $x=7k$.

In that case, let $m=k+x-2$.

Then $8x-14=7(k+x-2)=7m$, so $7|8x-14$.

On the other hand, if $7|8x-14$ then there is some integer $m$ such that $8x-14=7m$.

Letting $k=m-(x-2)$, we see that $x=7k$; i.e., $7|x$.